# Problem Signing Out with Devise on my App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am in the process updating my app so I use the Devise gem for authentication. Everything appears to be working great, except for the fact that I can't seem to sign out.

I get the error:

```
Couldn't find User with ID=sign_out
Parameters:
{"id"=>"sign_out"}
```

I can trace the error back to the show action in my users controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The problem is that I am not sure why it is trying to render the show action for my user. Overall my page has this format:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'shared/feed_home' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'shared/splash' %>
<% end %>
```

As per devise instructions, my sign-out path looks like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %></li>
```

If a user is not signed in, it should render the splash page which is basically static html. Any suggestions on how to help? Even if you could just put me in the right ball park in terms of the problem that would be much appreciated.

```
Here is my routes file:


  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :following_tags, :following_posts
    end
  end
  resources :posts 

  resources :votes
  resources :comments
  resources :tags
  resources :events

  #resources :posts,    :only => [:create, :destroy, :show]
  resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  root :to =>'pages#subscribed'


  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/live',   :to => "pages#home"
  match '/voted', :to => 'pages#highest_voted'
  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
```

Here is my rake routes:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)              {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                     {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
          following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format)       {:action=>"following", :controller=>"users"}
          followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format)       {:action=>"followers", :controller=>"users"}
     following_tags_user GET    /users/:id/following_tags(.:format)  {:action=>"following_tags", :controller=>"users"}
    following_posts_user GET    /users/:id/following_posts(.:format) {:action=>"following_posts", :controller=>"users"}
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                         POST   /users(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
                   votes GET    /votes(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"votes"}
                         POST   /votes(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"votes"}
                new_vote GET    /votes/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"votes"}
               edit_vote GET    /votes/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"votes"}
                    vote GET    /votes/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"votes"}
                         PUT    /votes/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"votes"}
                         DELETE /votes/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"votes"}
                comments GET    /comments(.:format)                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                         POST   /comments(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
             new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
            edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
                 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                         PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                         DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
                    tags GET    /tags(.:format)                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tags"}
                         POST   /tags(.:format)                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tags"}
                 new_tag GET    /tags/new(.:format)                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tags"}
                edit_tag GET    /tags/:id/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"tags"}
                     tag GET    /tags/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tags"}
                         PUT    /tags/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"tags"}
                         DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"tags"}
                  events GET    /events(.:format)                    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
                         POST   /events(.:format)                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"events"}
               new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"events"}
              edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"}
                   event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}
                         PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"events"}
                         DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"events"}
           relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"relationships"}
            relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"relationships"}
                    root        /(.:format)                          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"subscribed"}
                 contact        /contact(.:format)                   {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
                   about        /about(.:format)                     {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
                    live        /live(.:format)                      {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
                   voted        /voted(.:format)                     {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"highest_voted"}
                  signup        /signup(.:format)                    {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
```

Comment: Use this link for signout

[Sign Out Problem solved for Devise ]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually, ignore my previous answer and try this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
```

Comment: I am currently away from my computer and cannot test this. However, I will test it as soon as I get home. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. It looks like Devise isn't generating a get method for signout, just delete. The docs say it should, so not sure why it didn't. But it *should* work :-)

Comment: This is completely it - the route wants the delete method, not the get method.   `    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
`

Comment: Good solution. I encountered the same problem and this solved it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be in your `routes.rb` file. You need to route `user/signout` appropriately and it needs to be above the route for your users, because routes work from the top down. If you post your routes file, I can help more.

Do you maybe have a `resources :users` above your `devise_for :users`?

I guess you can also try scoping the devise routes:

```
    devise_scope :users do
      get "sign_out", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    end
```

Comment: Devise is supposed to provide that route automatically i thought? As per my most recent edit I am just linking to the default devise route for ending the session.

Comment: I also posted my routes file.

Comment: Yeah, see my update. For some reason rails thinks `sign_out` is an id for a users resource. What does `rake routes` give you?

Comment: Have you tried temporarily taking out the `resources :users` to see if the route works then?