# Signing out of App (that uses Devise) after Implementing Rails_admin (and moving to Rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-admin

UPDATE: /* I was able to fix the problem by setting up the asset pipeline as described in [Railscasts #282](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1)*/

I am using Devise for authentication in my app.  It was working fine until I added the gem Rails_admin.  I also moved to Rails 3.1 in the process so perhaps the problem is with the move to 3.1.

On signing out I get:

"Couldn't find User with id=sign_out"

It traces back to the users_controller's show action and in the params: `{"id"=>"sign_out"}`

The sign out link is in the application layout:

```
<%= link_to 'User Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

The corresponding route:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

This problem seems similar to: [Problem Signing Out with Devise on my App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596936/problem-signing-out-with-devise-on-my-app) except that I am specifying the delete method.

Follow on. . found this method in Devise:

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
```

Could anyone tell me how to dig further?  I.e. how to find 'resource_or_scope'?  The root_path looks fine in the routes.

Here's my routes.rb:

```
Notebook::Application.routes.draw do

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

  devise_for :owners

  match '/user' => 'users#dashboard', :as => :user_root
  match '/customer' => 'customers#dashboard', :as => :customer_root

  match 'users/dashboard' => 'users#dashboard'

  match 'customers/dashboard' => 'customers#dashboard'


  devise_for :users

  devise_for :customers

  resources :users

  resources :customers, :only => [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  root :to => 'misc#landing'
end
```

Comment: Are you using a custom sessions controller? Also let's take a look at your `routes.rb` file so we can see what is going on?

Comment: Not using a custom controller.  I think one fix, though I don't think it's preferable, would be to modify the sessions controller so that the redirect doesn't go to after_sign_out_path.  Added my routes.rb above.

Comment: The `after_sign_out_path` is just a callback for after the session is destroyed, and won't get you what you want. I have never used the rails_admin gem, and will have to dig more into it before I can know more of what is going on.

Comment: Your problem seems similar enough to a few I've ran into before, including my own problem. Check out my answer in this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808465/rails-devise-no-route-matches-logout/7099462#7099462]. Hope this helps!

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by setting up the asset pipeline as described in Railscast #282.