# Couldn't find User with id=sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Sign-out link isn't working in my rails application.

I have checked my routes.rb which is listed below and my application.html.erb looks to follow the right path.

Getting the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with id=sign_out
Rails.root: /Users/patrickwalsh/rails_projects/ytutorial

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `show'
lib/disable_assets_logger.rb:11:in `call'
```

My routes.rb

```
Refectory::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users" }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'login', to: "devise/sessions#new", as: "login"
    get 'logout', to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
    get 'logout', to: "users/sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
    get 'signup', to: "users#new", as: "signup"
    match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user
  end
  root :to => 'tutorials#index'

devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
end
  resources :tutorials
  resources :comments, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]

 resources :tutorials do
    member { post :vote }
  end

  if Rails.env == "development"
    match 'errors/404' => 'errors#error_404'
    match 'errors/500' => 'errors#error_500' 
  end

  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'
  end

  match 'tagged' => 'tutorials#tagged', :as => 'tagged'
end
```

and my application.html which seems to be following the right route from what I can see.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, (:method => "delete") %></li>
        <% else %>       
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <% end %>
```

My users controller as well as I have a suspicion this is where the problem lies but not sure what the error is.

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @tutorials = @user.tutorials
end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem Signing Out with Devise on my App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596936/problem-signing-out-with-devise-on-my-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move:

```
devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
```

over your `devise_scope`. Rails is looking for routes from top of Routes file. Your sign out url matches `users/:id`, hence it is trying to render show action with `sign_out` being an id.

UPDATE:

Actually, do you really need the last line in your `devise_scope` block?

Comment: Thanks @BroiSatse it was the bottom line in the `devise_scope` block that was breaking it.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: The better solution is from @bunofi https://stackoverflow.com/a/71108574/1735159

Insteade using link_to use button_to and does not need to change anything.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. My routes were in the correct order, the `link_to` method was properly used, and Rails kept triggering the `users/:id` route with `:id => :sign_out`. I figured out that was because I removed `jquery_ujs` from my `application.js` file...

`jquery_ujs` handles the `data-method` attribute in the links (generated by `link_to` when you use the *method* option), which is used to determine the correct route as explained here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs

So just make sure the you have the following included in your `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: This was absolutely correct. I copied a new bootstrap theme and suddenly this error was appearing. As soon as I added these back, it worked.

Comment: Awesome answer. Struggled with this for a while, and kept staring at the routes, which looked perfect. Alas, it was javascript!  I had 'jquery_ujs', but it was after my bootstrap, require so I changed the order to: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap

Answer (score 6):

I have started noticing this error after removing rails-ujs. This was done as part of the upgrade to Rails 7 with ImportMap and Hotwire suite. Changing `link_to` to `button_to` has fixed this error in this case.

```
<%= button_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality

Comment: This works ... but if I need to use the link_to?

Comment: <%= link_to "Delete post", post_path(post), data: { turbo_method: "delete" } %>

This seems to be an option too, right?

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling /users/sign_out directly from the URL it won't work because the routes is:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
```

id est, it uses the DELETE method. You need to change your devise initializer to:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

other option would be to create a small form and its button with DELETE as method.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
#form 

<%= link_to(destroy_user_session_path, {:class => "nav-link", :method => :delete}) do  %>
      <span class="sidebar-normal"> Logout </span>
<% end %>

#routes

devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

None of this solutions worked for me.
Also it happens just in development mode for me...
I fixed it by adding

```
  if params[:id] = "sign_out"
    sign_out current_user
    return
  end
```

in the set user function. Not the prettiest solution but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Since non of the other answers worked, I found that you could change the base path for every Devise endpoint as described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes#another-simple-way-to-do-the-same-thing). So, what I did was to user `devise_for` on `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users,
         path: 'devise'
```

Then, all my Devise routes started with `devise` instead of `users` so the conflict was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump this up but the "correct" anwser is not to mess around with routes risking breaking many things.

IF you want a disconnect on a GET then actually configure Devise like so in `initializer/devise.rb`

```
  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :get
```

As mentionned in the Devise documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use link_to with method DELETE

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path(current_user), method: :delete %>
```

explanation:
If you take a look at your Routes you'll see

Helper
destroy_user_session_path

the HTTP verb is
DELETE

the Path

/users/sign_out(.:format)

Controller#Action

devise/sessions#destroy

link_to defaoult method is get, this is "the why" (in a simplistic way of explaning). However,  you can specify by using method: :method name

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using [devise in a rails 7 app](https://medium.com/p/466619f6d627) (with bootstrap):

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out)
```

Make sure you start your server with `./bin/dev` (or else your javascripts won't work properly).

Even still, I also needed to use

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: "delete" } %>
```

Then logout worked.