# Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise in rails and I'm unable to logout of my user right now.

When I use the users/log_out page, it gives the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out
```

Anyway, here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
    redirect_to users_path
    else
    render 'new'
    end
end

  def index
    @users=User.all
  end

def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path
end

def update
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
    end

end
```

My route.rb :

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users do
  get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  resources :posts
  resources :users
end
```

My migration file for devise:

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

The application trace is as such:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:40:in `show'
```

Comment: in console it shows:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/all.js"):

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem Signing Out with Devise on my App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596936/problem-signing-out-with-devise-on-my-app)

Answer (score 5):

Verify that you have the following in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

The jquery_ujs stands for Unobtrusive JavaScript and this ensures many things (like delete method, e.g.) work as expected.

See Rafik's answer here: [Couldn't find User with id=sign_out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490555/couldnt-find-user-with-id-sign-out)

Answer (score 0):

The devise `users` route is matching before the `users/sign_out`. This is why it's trying to find a `User` with id `sign_out`.

Try changing the logout route, just

```
get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

should work.

I think POST is more appropriate for a logout action anyway:

```
post "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

Comment: hmm, it's still giving me the error sign. what would be the appropriate way of using POST

Comment: you should use something like this (haml):
`= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define your route using like this:

```
devise_for :users do
  delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post but I think the correct answer here is to change your method for that route from a get to a delete.

```
devise_for :users do
  delete "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

then in your view make sure your link_to has the delete method.

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session, :method => "delete"%>
```