# Rails Devise Signout not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am having issues logging out of my Rails app via Devise. I have looked at several different posts about this and have been struggling for a couple days now.

[couldnt-find-user-with-id-sign-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490555/couldnt-find-user-with-id-sign-out)

[couldnt-find-user-with-id-sign-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054399/couldnt-find-user-with-id-sign-out)

are some examples that have not worked so far. I have a feeling it is javascript related but I am not sure.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :events
devise_for :users
resources :users
resources :articles
resources :athletes

get 'welcome/index'
get 'athletes/index'
get 'users/login'
root 'welcome#index'
end
```

application.html.rb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Any advise or direction would be appreciated I am not sure where to go from here.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this be modifying ./config/initializers/devise.rb and changing

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: Did you mean `:get` instead of `:git`?

Comment: @SunilD. i literally do that all the time. you know how many times i've tried git generate scaffold x :P