# Routing Error with sign_out in devise in rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I've gone through many other stack overflow posts (e.g. this one: [No route matches "/users/sign_out" devise rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3)), but I've not found anything that works.

Here's my view:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

But when I click on the sign_out link, the server doesn't seem to process the "delete." It still thinks I want to a GET request.

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-03 20:45:54 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/sign_out"):
```

I've also including the javascript tag that the other SO threads have mentioned in my application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>    
<%= render 'layouts/stylesheets'%>
```

Totally at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding in `gem 'jquery-rails'` to your gem file, and run the generator as `rails g jquery:install --ui` to ensure that it installs JQueryUI as well as UJS.  If it asks to overwrite any files just choose 'yes'.

Also change the above to `<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>`

Once this is done try it once more - good luck!

Comment: After I did everything you mentioned (and only after doing everything), it worked. Thanks! Can you please explain why I needed to make those changes?

Comment: As I last recall, you needed UJS for it work.  In my experience, these steps have always fixed the issue for me in the past.