# Devise not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-mobile

I am creating rails mobile application using jQuery for mobile... and I am using devise for authentication, and I have created new controller called user controller to create userprofile page... until I create usercontroller devise was working properly but after creating user controller, after logging in `login` link will become `logout` link, if I refresh the page it will give a link to login but once again if I refresh the page it will show link to logout.

here is my routes

```
Kdproject::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'home#index'
 devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
  namespace :user do
    root :to => "pages#viewprofile"
  end
  match '/index', :to => 'users#index'
  match '/viewprofile', :to =>'pages#viewprofile'
```

Please help me to come out of this...

Comment: even 'edit/update user' is not working properly.. please help me..

Comment: Please write your question in a better way. Did you change your routes when you created Usercontroller?

Comment: yeah i have changed my routes... this is my routes
Kdproject::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'home#index'
 devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
  namespace :user do
    root :to => "pages#viewprofile"
  end
  match '/index', :to => 'users#index'
  match '/viewprofile', :to =>'pages#viewprofile'

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=devise just in case you'll get problems of this kind again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise has already a registrations controllers for this. If You want to add your own functionality there, you can inherit from the Registrations devise one:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update
    ... your code here
  end
end
```

and update your routes then:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

but if you just want to add more fields, it would be much easier to get devise views, and modify the one you need (views/devise/registrations/edit)
to get views:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Comment: here the problem is with sessions.. after logged out it wont destroy the session, and pls refer to my github repo and help me please....

Answer (score 0):

This is was happening because the compiled js and css in public folder.
problem solved by doing

```
rake assets:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include javascript for jquery and jquery_ujs ? If not include it in layout. For example :-

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs" %>
```

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3) too.