# Rails + devise: Trying to delete user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I try and delete my account in my rails app I get

No route matches "/users"

My View:

```
<p>We hate to see you go. <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>.</p>
```

My routes:

```
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                   PUT    /users(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                   DELETE /users(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: resource_name = user.  I just tried passing in current_user(which a user object) and I got the same result.

Comment: Never mind then... deleted my comment :-)

Comment: can you post your actual routes.rb file?

Comment: I find your problem similar with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3

Comment: at the top of my routes file is 'devise_for :users'

Comment: have you found a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 7):

According to your rake routes output, you need to use user_registration_path helper instead of just registration_path:

```
<p>
  We hate to see you go. 
  <%= link_to "Cancel my account", user_registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>.
</p>
```

And please double check if the link is triggered with the DELETE method (if the proper js files are included)

Comment: This gave me /users.user in my URL instead of just /users.  Thoughts?

Comment: I do have all my javascript files included.

Comment: yes, you're right, i was confused by user_registration in the rake routes. Do all other (especially update user registration) work correctly?

Comment: Yep ... all of my other deletes work as well so I know my javascript is correct. I am able to also destroy user_sessions which I know other people have had similar problems with devise but with the user session.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>
  Unhappy?
  <%= link_to "Cancel my account",
      registration_path(current_user),
      data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
      method: :delete %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using devise just do

```
<%= link_to "My Account", edit_user_registration_path %>
```