# Why doesn't my delete link work in Google Chrome?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just upgraded to rails `3.2.8` and devise `2.1.2`, totally wiping my User model to use the new migration and setup. I kept my old views though and started to test my user link to destroy/delete their own account. Now I tested this in Firefox and it works with out error, bringing up the confirm box and deleting the account if confirmed. In Google Chrome though I get no confirm box and it goes straight to:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/users"
```

This is my link as it should be:

```
  Unhappy? <%= link_to "Delete my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>.
```

Anyone else have this madness? Why does it not work for this browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813791/rails-devise-trying-to-delete-user-account

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you delete all cookies related to your project in Chrome and start again with a fresh sign up?

Comment: @Abram That didn't work either. Maybe it's a development thing. I'll try it in production soon.

Comment: Do you have a public github for this.. please link it for me, and I'll troubleshoot it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change my routes to be correct.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'join' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    put 'join' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'account_settings' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
    put 'account_settings' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => :update_user_registration
    get 'forgot_password' => 'devise/passwords#new', :as => :new_user_password
    get 'user', :to => 'user_pages#home', :as => :user_root
  end

  match '/user' => 'user_pages#home', :as => :user_root
```

and also add to the list:

```
delete 'join' => 'devise/registrations#destroy', :as => :user_registration
```

It could have also been that I redid my whole application from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You should see:

```
edit_user_registration   GET    /users/edit(.:format)            devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#destroy
```

when you run "rake routes" while in the project directory.

Try changing `"user_registration_path"` to `"edit_user_registration_path"`

Comment: Did you put: <%= link_to "Delete my account", edit_user_registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>

Comment: Yeah that's what it did. Still need to see what happens in production.

Comment: So I used it in production and it says the address is wrong or in others it doesn't work.