# Rails 3.1, Devise signout method dont work with namespace equal to devise_for

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

in my Rails app have this routes.rb:

```
 devise_for :admin
 namespace :admin do
     root :to  => 'dashboard#index'
     resources :customers 
 end
```

If try to logout with link_to('Logout',destroy_admin_session_path, :method => :delete), but 
rails print "No route matches [GET] "/admin/sign_out""

Is possible to fix without changes routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have resolved by setting GET method for sign_out action, not so secure but works. 
If anyone has the same problem this is the new routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admin, :sign_out_via => [ :get ]
 namespace :admin do
     root :to  => 'dashboard#index'
     resources :customers 
 end
```

If anyone have more secure fix is welcome

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `:method` option doesn't work since you ask a DELETE and have a GET. Make sure you have `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` in your layout

You may also read this question about the same problem : [No route matches "/users/sign_out" devise rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3)

Comment: have resolved by change "devise_for :admin" line in "devise_for :admin, :sign_out_via => [ :get ]"

Comment: PS: yep, have defaults javascript include

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old post but i had the same problem (not using devise but a custom solution)

and for me it was that in my application layout(named admin.html.erb because i had an admin namespace like you) i had to include the following line for it to work with delete and not get.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

what matters is the first part , i dont think turbolinks help this error at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this code is in head section in application.html.erb file, add if it's not. Works for me.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```