# Can I use :method => :delete with url_for()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication and creating an item in a dropdown for Sign Out. This is how I've built it:

```
<a href="<%= url_for(destroy_user_session_path) %>"><span data-icon="&#xe040;" /> Sign Out</a>
```

I'm using an icon font to stick a nice little image in to the left of the text. With Devise, it uses the DELETE verb for the `destroy_user_session_path` route. Most people would use a button_to or link_to but I don't think this will work for me. Using link_to is going to stick in the closing  tag automatically, which won't allow me to put my span tag in. Is there a way for me to build the above link and use the DELETE verb?

For now I'm using the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3). Specifically changing config.sign_out_via = :delete to config.sign_out_via = :get in devise.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `data-method="delete"` to your link tag. This is what `link_to` does when you call it with `:method => :delete`. JQuery does the rest of the work.

```
<a href="<%= url_for(destroy_user_session_path) %>" data-method="delete"><span data-icon="&#xe040;" /> Sign Out</a>
```