# Rails Bootstrap Gem on Top of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to rails and much of the devise login system has been generated for me. However, I tested my application before my twitter-bootstrap gem was applied, and a button I am concerned with now was previously correctly sending DEL requests.

However, it is now sending GET requests

HTML looks like

```
<li>
     <a href="/users/logout" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>
</li>
```

I'm still fairly new to the bootstrap gem, so I was wondering if the gem was dynamically changing some of the HTML? or why my tag clearly `says data-method="delete"` but still causes a GET request?

My Error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/logout"

Source: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails
```

Comment: Did the HTML for the button change after twitter bootstrap was added?

Comment: No, that was viewing the source from my chrome browser. So, it did not change, but I'm guessing bootstrap did change something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before beginning, I've copied sth from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3). First, there's no route for `users/logout` in Devise as default. It is defined as `/users/sign_out` default. You could change it on `routes.rb` under `config`. Instead of that, I'd like to offer this code to paste on your view file:

```
<li>
   <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
</li>
```