# Major issues with routes in Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I had fully working application until some day ago I started to get routing errors one by one.
Since debugging didn't help I rolled back routes.rb file to 3 weeks old version. In that time there wasn't any error at all for sure.But that didn't work.

I got errors only for specific actions.

1) On logout(Devise gem)

```
http://localhost:3000/lv/users/sign_out
```

error => `Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out` it is pointing to User controller

```
 private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])  # <= this line !!
    end
```

2) When I try to use Acts_as_votable gem ability to vote up for model. `http://localhost:3000/lv/advertisements/145/like` => `No route matches [GET] "/lv/advertisements/145/like"`

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   scope "(:locale)", :locale => /lv|ee|ru/ do  

           root 'home#index'
            get 'advertisements/update_regions' => 'advertisements#update_regions', as: 'update_regions'

              resources :replies do
              member do
                put "like", to: "replies#upvote"
                put "dislike", to: "replies#downvote"
              end
            end

            resources :reviews do
              member do
                put "like", to: "reviews#upvote"
                put "dislike", to: "reviews#downvote"
              end
            end

      resources :advertisements do
         collection { post :search, to: 'advertisements#index' }
            member do
              put "like", to: "advertisements#upvote"
              put "dislike", to: "advertisements#downvote"
            end
      end
     resources :services
      get "/help", to: "help#index"
      get "/rules", to: "rules#index"

      get "/blacklist", to: "blacklist#index"
     devise_for :users

     resources :users, only: [:show, :index] do
        member do
           put "like", to: "users#upvote"
           put "dislike", to: "users#downvote"

         end
       end

    resource :user, only: [:edit] do
       collection do
        patch 'update_password'
     end
    end

  resources :types

  resources :feedbacks
  resources "men-blacklist", :controller => :men_blacklist, :as => :men_blacklist 
    resources "girl-blacklist", :controller => :girl_blacklist, :as => :girl_blacklist 

  get 'sms/receive/', to: 'sms#receive' 
  get 'girl_blacklist/index'

  resources :hours

  get 'replies/show'

        devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)   

  resources :reports
 #get "/accept" => 'home#accept_and_redirect'
 mount Judge::Engine => '/judge'

end

end
```

I can't remember maybe I installed some gem in that time before errors started. But does that could be the case?

Comment: Found solution. I was missing application.js file that requires jquery_ujs :)

Comment: More info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3?rq=1