# Getting devise sign_out error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error i am getting

```
No route matches [GET] "/retailers/sign_out"
```

my routes file

```
  devise_for :retailers
  devise_for :suppliers
  devise_for :admins, skip: [:registration]
```

And the rake routes

```
destroy_retailer_session_path   DELETE  /retailers/sign_out(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy
```

Why can't i sign out?

Comment: You are calling the signout via GET, but based on rake routes it only supports DELETE

Comment: See this for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3

Comment: i have this in my view `<li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_retailer_session_path,method: :delete%></li>`

Comment: First verify you are requiring rails_ujs in your application.js file .  Is your link_to is in a hidden or not created panel called by javascript?  For instance, if you have a hidden fly-out panel someone clicks on which unhides it or renders it - then click log ?

Comment: Whoa this worked. THANKS.

Comment: heh, glad you got it - should be jquery_ujs, not rails ujs.  but you seem to have resolved that.

Comment: Yes it was jquery ujs. You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
   method: :delete
```

to your Sign-out link_to to perform DELETE HTTP request instead of default GET

Comment: this is how my views look `<li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_retailer_session_path,method: :delete%></li>`

Comment: @suyesh Do you really click on that link ?
Where is this link situated ?

Comment: @suyesh Could you inspect in HTML ?
Do you see this in built html

       data-method="delete"
?